# Grid result not match the export result in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sql, import-products

I created a module for some data logging with widget grid display and csv export function.

Inside the collection, I added a new columns with mysql function "IF(DATE_FORMAT(updated_at,'%H:%i') = '16:30',DATE_FORMAT(updated_at,'%Y-%m-%d'),'')"

The result is correct in the exported csv but not for grid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Magento do NOTHING wrong.

Most probably you didn't set the correct timezone in DB. If you didn't set it, the time will be treated as UTC. And you definitely set GMT+8 in Magento, so you can notice that the time in Magento is 8 hours greater than the time in CSV.

For DB side, check the timezone setting first by running this SQL:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```

If it returns 00:00:00 it means your timezone is set to UTC on DB side. To fix it, run this command:

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';
```

Of course, you may need to re-import the products if the time doesn't show correctly.