# Magento 2.4.4 order export csv wrong data

Tags: magento2, category

I am using magento 2.4.4.
I am getting wrong "purchase date in CSV".

Purchase date on order - Aug 31, 2021 9:19:46 PM.
On csv - 2021-09-01 01:19:46.

From where its data gets set in csv ?
[image]

Comment: Have you set proper Root category from the store level first?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: This Blog might help. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257693/product-saleable-qty-not-showing-and-update-in-magento-2-3

Comment: `cataloginventory_stock` might be an old table, it shouldn't have more than one record or so I'd imagine. Be aware that custom extensions can also cause tons of issues with inventory stock. Since I think we'd need more information on your database and what data/tables are most likely missing, try this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213282/salable-quantity-in-magento-2-3-dont-show and this one: https://magecomp.com/blog/product-with-salable-qty-0-is-not-considered-out-of-stock-magento-2/

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: what is the timezone of the shop? see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179096/grid-result-not-match-the-export-result-in-magento-2

Comment: Is time zone set properly or check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed using this, try.

File name :Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider

```
public function getRowData(DocumentInterface $document, $fields, $options): array
        {
            $row = [];
            foreach ($fields as $column) {
                if (isset($options[$column])) {
                    $key = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
                    if (isset($options[$column][$key])) {
                        $row[] = $options[$column][$key];
                    } else {
                        $row[] = $key;
                    }
                } else {
                    if($column == "created_at"){
                        $convertedDate = $this->localeDate->date(
                        new DateTime($document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue(), new DateTimeZone('GMT')),
                        $this->locale,
                        true
                        );
                        $created_at = new DateTime($convertedDate->format($this->dateFormat));
                        $row[] = $created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    }else{
                        $row[] = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return $row;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento will export the created date in UTC. if your store use another timezone, the time will be diffrent in the order grid (timezone of your store) and in the exported csv.
To get the order created date in your timezone, you can add a custom column to the csv. See [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289372/add-custom-column-to-grid-that-can-be-exported) or [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315854/magento-2-how-to-add-new-column-in-order-csv-export).

Answer (score 1):

Just checked in version 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 and both versions works correct for Order and export into CSV

First: check your locale in configuration

Second: check the date in database (`sales_order`)

How and why it should work:

See `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- ... -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="created_at" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                </item>
                <!-- ... -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Please check if you didn't overwrite this in di or has incorrect plugin for

See implementation in `\Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider`

```
namespace Magento\Ui\Model\Export;

// ...

class MetadataProvider
{
    // ...
    public function convertDate($document, $componentName): void
    {
        if (!isset($this->data[$componentName])) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($this->data[$componentName] as $field) {
            $fieldValue = $document->getData($field);
            if (!$fieldValue) {
                continue;
            }
            $convertedDate = $this->localeDate->date(
                new DateTime($fieldValue, new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
                $this->locale,
                true
            );
            $document->setData($field, $convertedDate->format($this->dateFormat));
        }
    }
}
```

The method calls in `\Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv::getCsvFile`